# iOS universal app which launch image

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm writing a universal app that supports rotation. When app starts, it needs to download some data from internet, so I push a UIViewController with activity indicator, because it is not possible to have animated launch images or add labels or objects to it.

I would like the "loading" VC has the same bg image as launch, but, because it is a universal app, I can't set a simple [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] because it can running on iPhone or iPad and if iPad can be launched in portrait or landscape (iPhone apps always start in portrait).

The question is: there's a way to know which Default.png has been used as launch image? it can be

- Default.png (@2x if retina)
- Default-Portrait.png (@2x if retina)
- Default-Landscape.png (@2x if retina)
- Default-568h@2x.png

If there's now way, I will check currentDevice and orientation and set imageNamed manually.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no suffix for portrait and landscape. You will have to check the orientation manually with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`.

For showing different images for the iPad and iPhone/iPod Touch, you can add `~ipad` onto the end of the iPad image and `~iphone` onto the end of the iPhone/iPod Touch image. Example:

Default~iphone.png will load on iPhone/iPod Touch and Default~ipad.png will load on iPad with this:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
```

There is also no specifier for iPhone 5 though. So you will have to check `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` and again load the `UIImage` manually.

---

**FULL (untested) EXAMPLE:**

```
UIImage *image;

if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h-Landscape"];
    }
    else
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h-Portrait"];
    }
}
else
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape"];
    }
    else
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait"];
    }
}
// check suggested by Guy Kogus
if (image == nil) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
```

---

To answer your question in the comments:

No, you cannot query what launch image was used at runtime.

Comment: There is a suffix for portrait or landscape. If you want to see for certain, create a dummy project and have 2 images, one 1024x768 and the other 768x1024. Go to the project settings and drag the images in the Launch Images section and you'll see that Xcode automatically names them with the required -Landscape or -Portrait suffixes (or is it suffices?).

Comment: Yeah but I don't think that works when using `-[UIImage imageNamed:]`

Comment: No, you have to add those suffixes manually. But that's fairly easy, you just have to use the status bar's orientation.

Comment: To the end of your code, I would recommend adding an `if` statement to check if there is still no image, in which case just take `image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];`

Comment: Also, there's no need for the .png at the ond of the image names. UIImage handles that automatically.

Comment: I knew how to do that in your way, I said "I will check currentDevice and orientation and set imageNamed manually". I wanted to know if there's some system variable that contains the launch image used, so It would be enough get this var and use it to name the UIImage. Thanks, I will use the "long way". Call me lazy ;))

Comment: @masgar No, you can't request the launch image at runtime.

Comment: @masgar I also added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The @2x suffix is automatically chosen, so you don't need to worry about that. There are a few checks that you need to implement:

```
- (NSString *)defaultImage
{
    NSString *imageName = nil;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
        {
            imageName = @"Default-568h";
        }
        else
        {
            imageName = @"Default";
        }
    }
    else // ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
        {
            imageName = @"Default-Landscape";
        }
        else // if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
        {
            imageName = @"Default-Portrait";
        }
    }
    return [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, see my comment to Bo A answer.